# How to find what package to bug apport

Tags: lubuntu, kubuntu

How to find what package to apport commande ubuntu-bug against to use?

```
xprop WM_CLASS
dpkg -S "\/bin/$(xprop WM_CLASS | cut -d "\"" -f2)"
```

Cant find Keyboard System settings package for example.

[image]

Comment: It's in your output: `kcmshell5` is an application provided by the `kde-cli-tools` package.

Comment: By the way, for Kubuntu, I prefer filing bugs at https://bugs.kde.org if the issue isn't a general Ubuntu issue.

Comment: Oh, so i just reported to wrong package? But result got correct on 2nd command? 2nd command finds package name?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "*result got correct on 2nd command*"

Comment: 2nd command in terminal from picture gave this package option in front of line.